# Hibernate generates multiple select statements

Tags: hibernate

Not getting why multiple selects are needed, here are the classes

```
DrivingLicense.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DRIVING_LICENSE")
public class DrivingLicense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "LICENSE_NUMBER")
    private int licenseNumber;
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_ISSUE")
    private Date dateOfIssue;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "drivingLicense", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Person person;
}

Person.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private int personId;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String personName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "D_LICENSE_NUMBER")
    private DrivingLicense drivingLicense;
}

TestClass

TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createQuery("from Person p", Person.class);
query.getResultList();
```

here `query.getResultList` is generating following sqls

```
Hibernate: select person0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_1_, person0_.D_LICENSE_NUMBER as D_LICENSE_NUMBER3_1_, person0_.PERSON_NAME as PERSON_NAME2_1_ from PERSON person0_
Hibernate: select drivinglic0_.LICENSE_NUMBER as LICENSE_NUMBER1_0_0_, drivinglic0_.DATE_OF_ISSUE as DATE_OF_ISSUE2_0_0_, person1_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_1_1_, person1_.D_LICENSE_NUMBER as D_LICENSE_NUMBER3_1_1_, person1_.PERSON_NAME as PERSON_NAME2_1_1_ from DRIVING_LICENSE drivinglic0_ left outer join PERSON person1_ on drivinglic0_.LICENSE_NUMBER=person1_.D_LICENSE_NUMBER where drivinglic0_.LICENSE_NUMBER=?
Hibernate: select person0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_ID1_1_1_, person0_.D_LICENSE_NUMBER as D_LICENSE_NUMBER3_1_1_, person0_.PERSON_NAME as PERSON_NAME2_1_1_, drivinglic1_.LICENSE_NUMBER as LICENSE_NUMBER1_0_0_, drivinglic1_.DATE_OF_ISSUE as DATE_OF_ISSUE2_0_0_ from PERSON person0_ left outer join DRIVING_LICENSE drivinglic1_ on person0_.D_LICENSE_NUMBER=drivinglic1_.LICENSE_NUMBER where person0_.D_LICENSE_NUMBER=?
```

why 2 selects are needed I don't know. in both the table there is only one record.

Comment: is it the problem due to bidirectional relationship? if yes then how to solve it?

Comment: Your associations are not LAZY, so Hibernate loads everything.

Comment: What happens when you execute `"from DrivingLicense dl"` on the same data set?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate EAGERly loads by default associations, LAZY load them as follows.
This is famous [Hibernate N+1 select problem](http://learningviacode.blogspot.ch/2012/07/the-n-1-select-problem-in-hibernate.html)

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```